# android : using image in a class as a property

Tags: android, image, class

//my code is like:

```
enum Quality{
    usable, clean, dirty, inevitable;
}

public class Wc {
    public String address;
    public Image image;
    public Quality quality;

public Wc(String st,Image im,Quality q){
    address=st;
    image=im;
    quality=q;

}
}
```

//  how should I use the constructor or give it the image path?

Comment: where are that images?are they  in drawable folder? Try using Bitmap instead of Image.

Comment: @user3693550 yes they are in drawable and im using bitmap now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public myClass extends Activity{
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       Bitmap image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),
        R.drawable.image1);
       Wc wc = new Wc(yourString,image1, yourQuality);
   }
}
```